# Archive option greyed out in xcode 4.5.2

Tags: xcode, upload, archive

I have created app using Xcode.It is ready to be uploaded on iTunes connect..
But application loader seems to be too slow to do so..
The other archive method looks good to use but the option is disabled in Xcode 4.5.2

Actions:
I tried editing the schemes and selected archive (Release option)and also the destination to my device...
I also Built after that
I set SKIP INSTALL in target to NO.

I followed instruction seeing few posts on this forum as well..
But none seems to be working for me

I dnt knw how to get that option avtive agn...
My app is on my itouch and working properly..so there is no device issue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Archive menu item is greyed out because your scheme destination is a simulator.  You must be building for a device or for “iOS Device” to Archive.

Comment: This is nothing to do with the device. You don't need to even have a device connected, just choose to build for device in your scheme and then "Product" >> "Archive"... and it works as long as you have a valid Distribution profile

Comment: Haha! I didn't notice that my scheme was still set to the iPhone Simulator. Setting to iOS Device worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With the latest XCode application version this option has new name.

You can choose option "Any iOS Device (arm64)" in new versions of XCode and this will enable "Archive" Button in your XCode Application on mac.

This is as per Xcode Version 14.3.1

[image]